# Can the Kiki/bouba effect be generalized?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, linguistic-universals, anthropology

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect

Has the Kiki/bouba effect been generalized in research, in which qualitative associations for phonemic units are explored comprehensively, enuneratively, via “matching”? (Like, a principle where instead of studying what “inherent” properties something has, it is better to study how the relationship between A and B compares to C and D).

You could develop an ontology, a classification, on any sensory domain - color, shape, texture, speed, any cognitive or sensory element, or connotation at all, like “scary”, “mean”, or “tall”, or something arbitrary like “Micky Mouse” (as a control).

On a large sample size (maybe even deployable via an app or software), ask people what their associations are between randomly generated phoneme clusters and randomly selected qualities (comparatively - like a vision test where they ask you, lens 1 or lens 2).

I suppose the topic of the field would be, language nativism or innateness: how much of language is due to parameters that originate in the brain, as opposed to a fortiori.